# Graphics2D - Math plot - Ploygon - how to get all plot points

Tags: java, math, graphics2d

I've just tried to write "line" code to visualize a simple math;
Here it is

```
Ploygon polygon=new Ploygon();
int x,y;


ploygon.addPoint(0,0);   
polygon.addPoint(width,height);

g.drawPolygon(polygon);
```

The code gives y=x effect;

OK... it is quite simple code; But the thing I am interested to get is points each N pixels during the statement period as {x0,y0}{0,0} and {x1,y1} {width,height} and that is the problem :(

The polygon xpoints array is not handy because it may contain just the same points which were added when addPoint(x,y) method was invoked; so in my case there just two added points which are connected by Polygon but what about all the rest points which stay between these points {x0,y0}{0,0} and {x1,y1} {width,height}  ? How to get them?

For example. Coming back to the previous snippet how to find out what point x,y value is when **(height%N)=0** etc?

Is there the most optimal way?

Thanks

Comment: See also [Adding a point to `Polygon`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5878090/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to realise here is that you are no longer working with pixels/coordinates per se, but you are working with vectors. You'd get much the same image from a polygon contained the coordinates `(-500,-500)` and `(500,500)` which is drawn onto a `Graphics` object which represents the (clipped) area from `(0,0)` in the bottom left to `(100,100)` in the bottom right. (ignoring for now that the actual coordinate system of `Graphics` has an inverted y-axis).

Therefore you have to solve this in a more back-to-basic's Math way rather than a “read the pixels” way. Unless you just want to determine if a given point is *in* the shape (for which the `Shape` interface offers a built-in method), you would be looking at calculating the slope of a line and determining functions which represent your line. For instance continuing from the example you have two points (-500,-500) and (500,500) which gives a slope of 1000/1000 = 1. So you could rewrite that function in terms of your x-coordinates as `f(x) = -500 + (x + 500)`. Then if you want to know if the point (100,200) is on that line all you need to do is calculate `f(100)` and see that it isn't.

Getting back to your example, finding points which match a predicate (height%N =0), we'd be looking for `f(x) == 0 mod N` and so 'all' you'd need to do is solve the equation for x.

Comment: "Getting back to your example, finding points which match a predicate (height%N =0), we'd be looking for f(x) == 0 mod N and so 'all' you'd need to do is solve the equation for x." 
It is all fine but what if the f(x)!=N ? I mean it is not integer so there is no way to get right x,y coordinate? What goes if the plot statement is like "y=x*tan(a/b)+coeff" for example? Is there a way to detect this kind of function points to keep them let's say in an array?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that would be solved by rounding your answer to the nearest integer?

Comment: Emm... The Math.round() you mean? OK I'll try it and report my results