# Java - Drawing a dynamic shape outline

Tags: java, swing, graphics, shapes, graphics2d

I wish to create a dynamic outline to a `Shape` (AWT) by adding objects (with draw functions) to appropriate positions on screen along the shape's perimeter. I want a roughly even distance between each object. (An alternative approach to the same affect will be fine.)

How might I acquire the locations for these objects?  I know shapes have a path iterator, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: ...what is the question?

Comment: How might I acquire the locations for these objects? I know shapes have a path iterator, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: If 3 points were added to form a triangular shape, only those 3 points would be returned in the path iterator.

Comment: And what of a circle? How many points would be returned then? 2? In which case how would I then create 20 evenly spaced objects along its perimeter? That is what I'm after here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might look at a library such as the one described in [*A Shape Diagram Editor*](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-diagram-editor/shape.html).

If you want to experiment, [`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) is a simple object drawing program that features moveable, resizable, colored nodes connected by edges. If the nodes were a little smaller, they'd be moveable points on a `Shape` that can be iterated as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5878090/230513) for `Polygon`.

Addendum: *I want a roughly even distance between each object.*

The `class Node` exposes a number of static methods that operate on a `List<Node>` such as `selected`. Existing implementations serve, for example, to translate or resize multiple selections as a unit.  Functions for `Align` and `Distribute` could be implemented similarly. I'd look at `LayoutManger` as an example for the latter.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Good point; I overlooked that aspect of the question. More above.

Comment: I don't see how this helps. The problem in question is finding an evenly distributed number of points along a shape's perimeter. Perhaps I wasn't very clear on that.

Comment: It would depend on the `Shape`; here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2510048/230513) that relies on the parametric equation of a circle. It could be generalized using the parametric equation for an ellipse.

Comment: So there's no simple way to just get equally distributed points on any shape?

Comment: I don't see such a method in the [`Shape`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface, but you can create your own sub-interface and delegate to existing implementations that you intend to support.

Answer (score 2):

Use `FlatteningPathIterator` to get points for `Shape's` path.

Also you can use `BasicStroke's` method

```
public Shape createStrokedShape(Shape s)
```

to get `Shape's` outline with desire width.