# JFreeChart XYSplineRenderer piecewise polynomial string

Tags: java, jfreechart, spline

I have an applet that displays a spline using JFreeChart. Is there a way to get a string representation of the piecewise polynomial? I can write a method that uses getX and getY from XYSeries to calculate it myself, but I'm just wondering if there's a built in way. I could not find it in the JFreeChart api, but perhaps I missed it. I also looked around for other libraries but found nothing.

Comment: I wrote two methods that write the splines to a string. Some people might find the method that gives the cubic polynomial from 4 known coordinates useful. Calculating the coefficients was particularly tricky, but I found Maple to be helpful.

Comment: The add comment feature here says I can't post that many characters. Is there any way I can post my code?

Answer (score 1):

The parent class of `XYSplineRenderer` is [`XYLineAndShapeRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.html) that contains a nested [`State`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYLineAndShapeRenderer.State.html) class holding the `GeneralPath` from which you can obtain the [`PathIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html). This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5878090/230513) examines the `PathIterator` of a `Polygon`, which contains only straight line segments. Presumably, a `GeneralPath` will include quadratic and cubic segments.